# Meaning of Attribution in CC BY 3.0 for a JavaScript library

Tags: creative-commons, attribution, source-code, cc-by, website

I come across a JavaScript library which is licensed under the [CC BY 3.0 (US)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/) license.

The only restrictions of the license is

> Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.

I would like to know for a JavaScript library, what is the correct way of attribution? Do I have to list the library title, author in every page of the website? Or as long as I keep the license term inside the JavaScript source file then it will be fine?

Answer (score 1):

You are using this library to help run the Web Site?  Then the web pages that you send are output from something that uses the library.  From my understanding (I am not a Lawyer, just someone who has been hanging around the Free and Open Source communities for more than 3 decades), you only need to include the attribution if you are redistributing the source (with or without modification).  But, you aren't.  The only consumer of the software is thus you.  So, you don't *need* to do anything.

That having been said, it might be a nice gesture if you did mention them on a "Credits" or "About this Site" page, or even in a section at the bottom of the page.  On my web site, I have a little banner section at the bottom of every page with logos for the tools I use, that link to their pages.

And needless to say, I am not a Lawyer and This is not Legal Advice.  You may need to get a legal opinion, in that case you need to talk to a lawyer.

Comment: As OP asks about JavaScript, it seems likely that this JavaScript code runs on the client-side (i.e., in the visitor’s browser). If so, it is some kind of redistributing, no? The visitor can check the page’s source code and find the JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "correct" ways to do attribution and no one polices it. The libraries should already have their own in-tact license statements. You can consider providing a credit and link on an about page, on a credits page.

If it's not cluttery, I've taken to putting the credits in the footer of my GitHub powered pages, e.g.

[image]